# Multivalue processing in the context of the modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, features

I am new to python so please bear with me. I have the following script that is supposed to get a multivalue parameter of several shapefiles as an input and then run the unionanalysis on all these shapefules to create a single feature class or shapefile output. The script seems to run fine however only processes up to step 2 of 16 and does not create any output file. I do have the output file specified however and all the parameters are in the right order with the input accepting multivalue variables and both having feature class as their data type. I need to precise that this is within the ModelBuilder framework...

Here is the script:

```
    import arcpy

    myList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

    unionResult = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    arcpy.Union_analysis(myList, unionResult, "ALL", "", True)
```

To further clarify:

Parameter (0) is an input, feature class, multivalue (yes)
Parameter (1) is an output, feature class, multivalue (No)

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should split the string variable in order to get a list:

```
myList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0).split(";")
```

A thread at the ESRI forum [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51953) reports that spaces in the path can produce an error, so you can `.strip("'")` the extra single quotes around the file path.

```
myList = [x.strip("'") for x in myList]
```

In addition, check the `Union_analysis` parameters. The `cluster_tolerance` is a linear unit, so it has to be something like this:

```
arcpy.Union_analysis(myList, unionResult, "ALL", 0.0003, True)
```

Comment: I tried this and I got an error (which is better than the nothing I was getting before). So the error states

Comment: What the error states ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/5SIWvg9.png?1

Comment: "Parameters are not valid"

Comment: This error can occur if you have misspelled folder names, use backslashes instead of forward slashes or have spaces in the path names (like in your case). Can you try:
`myList = [x.strip("'") for x in myList]`
`arcpy.Union_analysis(myList, unionResult, "ALL", 0.0003, True)`

Comment: @user32882 If you wish to pursue the "Parameters are not valid" error it could be worth researching/asking it separately so that this Q&A remains focussed on your original problem.